# SQL Sub Query splitting results into two rows

Tags: sql, join, subquery, case, multiple-results

I have a SQL query that uses sub query's to calculate some results from tables not used in the main query. I have an issue where the results for the individual results (2.1 & 2.2) are being put on two lines, so the 2.1 result is there and 2.2 is 0 on one line and vice versa. I want it to be like the Expected results below.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT

    DATEPART(week, SS.timearrived) 
        AS [Week No],

    SS.timearrived
        AS [Date],

    RTRIM(SS.vname)
        AS [V Name],    

    SS.vyid
        AS [Vy ID],

    ((SELECT CASE WHEN
                 (select COUNT(*)
    FROM  IME 
    WHERE IME.topos = SS.visid  and XCHE.sname IN ('2.1','2.2')
                      AND movek != 'Y' AND movek != 'S'
    GROUP BY IME.topos) IS NULL
    THEN '0'
    else (select COUNT(*)
    FROM  IME 
    WHERE IME.topos = SS.visid  and XCHE.sname IN ('2.1','2.2')
                      AND movek != 'Y' AND movek != 'S'
    GROUP BY IME.topos)
    END )

     + (SELECT CASE WHEN
                 (select COUNT(*)
    FROM  IME 
    WHERE IME.fmpos = SS.visid  and XCHE.sname IN ('2.1','2.2')
    GROUP BY IME.fmpos) IS NULL
    THEN '0'
    else (select COUNT(*)
    FROM  IME 
    WHERE IME.fmpos = SS.visid and XCHE.sname IN ('2.1','2.2')
    GROUP BY IME.fmpos)
    END)
    )/(
    convert(float,datediff(mi, swork, ework))/60 )

        AS [GBP T2],

    ((SELECT CASE WHEN
                 (select COUNT(*)
    FROM  IME 
    WHERE IME.topos = SS.visid  and XCHE.sname IN ('2.1')
                      AND movek != 'Y' AND movek != 'S'
    GROUP BY IME.topos) IS NULL
    THEN '0'
    else (select COUNT(*)
    FROM  IME 
    WHERE IME.topos = SS.visid  and XCHE.sname IN ('2.1')
                      AND movek != 'Y' AND movek != 'S'
    GROUP BY IME.topos)
    END )

     + (SELECT CASE WHEN
                 (select COUNT(*)
    FROM  IME 
    WHERE IME.fmpos = SS.visid  and XCHE.sname IN ('2.1')
    GROUP BY IME.fmpos) IS NULL
    THEN '0'
    else (select COUNT(*)
    FROM  IME 
    WHERE IME.fmpos = SS.visid and XCHE.sname IN ('2.1')
    GROUP BY IME.fmpos)
    END)
    )/(
    convert(float,datediff(mi, swork, ework))/60 )

        AS [GCP 2.1],

    ((SELECT CASE WHEN
                 (select COUNT(*)
    FROM  IME 
    WHERE IME.topos = SS.visid  and XCHE.sname IN ('2.2')
                      AND movek != 'Y' AND movek != 'S'
    GROUP BY IME.topos) IS NULL
    THEN '0'
    else (select COUNT(*)
    FROM  IME 
    WHERE IME.topos = SS.visid  and XCHE.sname IN ('2.2')
                      AND movek != 'Y' AND movek != 'S'
    GROUP BY IME.topos)
    END )

     + (SELECT CASE WHEN
                 (select COUNT(*)
    FROM  IME 
    WHERE IME.fmpos = SS.visid  and XCHE.sname IN ('2.2')
    GROUP BY IME.fmpos) IS NULL
    THEN '0'
    else (select COUNT(*)
    FROM  IME 
    WHERE IME.fmpos = SS.visid and XCHE.sname IN ('2.2')
    GROUP BY IME.fmpos)
    END)
    )/(
    convert(float,datediff(mi, swork, ework))/60 )

        AS [GCP 2.2]

    FROM    SS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN VCME ON SS.visid = vgk 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN VVVD ON SS.visid = fs01
    LEFT OUTER JOIN VCS ON VVVD.vvdgk = VCS.vvdgk
    LEFT OUTER JOIN VCSD ON VCS.gk = VCSD.csgk
    INNER JOIN XCHE on VCS.cgk = XCHE.gk
```

**Current Results**

```
    Week No     Date                        V Name      Vy ID       GBP T2      GCP 2.1     GCP 2.2
    14          2013-03-31 00:01:00.000     FORD        30580       18.72       0           18.72
    14          2013-03-31 00:01:00.000     FORD        30580       18.72       18.72       0
```

**Expected Results**

```
    Week No     Date                        V Name      Vy ID       GBP T2      GCP 2.1     GCP 2.2
    14          2013-03-31 00:01:00.000     FORD        30580       18.72       18.72       18.72
```

Comment: Plz share schema structure if possible

Comment: The structure is just based around the joins on the bottom, there are no other links between tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your final query, use this as the outermost query to get the result what you want.

```
SELECT    `Week No` ,      Date  ,   `V Name`, `Vy ID`,  `GBP T2`,
MAX(`GCP 2.1`), MAX(`GCP 2.2`) 
FROM
( -------------------  REST OF THE INNER QUERY HERE  --------------)
GROUP BY  `Week No` ,      Date  ,   `V Name`, `Vy ID`,  `GBP T2`;
```